# Swing - timer does not stop when memory game is over

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I am trying to create a memory game where you have 12 togglebuttons. If you click one button, the icon would change. If two icons match then both are flipped. I have an elapsed timer on display at the top of the game. I want to make the timer stop when the game ends; however, the timer just keeps on going. This is what I have:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.time.*;

public class MemoryGame extends JToggleButton implements ActionListener {

private Timer cdTimer;
private Timer swTimer;

private int count = 0;
private long start;
private long begin = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

private JToggleButton[] buttons;
private JToggleButton last;
private JLabel time;
//private String[] commandID = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"};
ArrayList<ImageIcon> iconList = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<JToggleButton> retireButton = new ArrayList();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("MemoryGame.png");


public MemoryGame() {
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Memory Game");

    jfrm.setSize(1000, 1000);

    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jfrm.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

    time = new JLabel("Elapsed time is 00:00:00");

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3,4);

    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setLayout(layout);

    createIcons();

    buttons = new JToggleButton[12];

    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton(icon);

        buttons[i] = btn;

        //buttons[i].setActionCommand(commandID[i]);

        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

        gamePanel.add(buttons[i]);   
    }

    //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(buttons));
    //Collections.shuffle(iconList);

    jfrm.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    time.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    time.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    jfrm.add(time, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    jfrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    jfrm.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    timerStart();

    JToggleButton btn = (JToggleButton)e.getSource();

    setIcon(btn);
    if(last == null){
        last = btn;
        return;
    }

    matching(btn, last);

    last = null;

}

public void updateTime(){
    long temp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    time.setText("Elapsed time is " + formatTime((long) (temp - begin)) + "-"+retireButton.size());
}

public static String formatTime(long ms){
    long millis = ms % 1000;
    long x = ms / 1000;
    long seconds = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    long minutes = x % 60;
    x /= 60;
    long hours = x % 24;

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
}

private void timerStart(){
    ActionListener timerAL = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            updateTime();
        }
    };
    swTimer = new Timer(1000, timerAL);
    swTimer.start();
}

private void timerStop(){
    if(retireButton.size() == 12){
        long stop = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        time.setText("Elapsed time is " + formatTime((long)(stop-begin)));
        swTimer.stop();
    }
}
private void setIcon(JToggleButton btn) {
    if(btn == buttons[0] || btn == buttons[1])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(0)); 

    else if(btn == buttons[2] || btn == buttons[3])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(1));

    else if(btn == buttons[4] || btn == buttons[5])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(2));

    else if(btn == buttons[6] || btn == buttons[7])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(3));

    else if(btn == buttons[8] || btn == buttons[9])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(4));

    else if(btn == buttons[10] || btn == buttons[11])
        btn.setIcon(iconList.get(5));
}

private void matching(JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    if(btn.isSelected()){
        if(btn2.isSelected()){
            buttonDisable(btn, btn2);
            if(!btn.getIcon().toString().equals(btn2.getIcon().toString())){
                startTime(1, btn, btn2);
            }
            else {
                retirePair(btn, btn2);
                timerStop();
                buttonEnable(btn, btn2);
            }
        }
    }   
}

private void startTime(int countPassed, JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(count == 0){
                cdTimer.stop();
                unflipPair(btn, btn2);
                buttonEnable(btn, btn2);
            }
            else
                count--;
            }

    };
    cdTimer = new Timer(500, action);
    cdTimer.start();
    count = countPassed;
}

private void buttonEnable(JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    if(retireButton.isEmpty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            if(buttons[i] != btn && buttons[i] != btn2)
                buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
        }
    }    
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < retireButton.size(); j++){        
                if(buttons[i] != btn && buttons[i] != btn2 && buttons[i] != retireButton.get(j))
                    buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            }   
        }
    }
}

private void buttonDisable(JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        if(buttons[i] != btn && buttons[i] != btn2)
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
private void unflipPair(JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    btn.setIcon(icon);
    btn2.setIcon(icon);
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    btn2.setEnabled(true);
    btn.setSelected(false);
    btn2.setSelected(false);
}

private void retirePair(JToggleButton btn, JToggleButton btn2){
    btn.setEnabled(false);
    btn2.setEnabled(false);
    btn.setSelected(true);
    btn2.setSelected(true);
    retireButton.add(btn);
    retireButton.add(btn2);
}

private void createIcons(){
    ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("1.png");
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("2.png");
    ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("3.png");
    ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon("4.png");
    ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon("5.png");
    ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon("6.png");

    iconList.add(icon1);
    iconList.add(icon2);
    iconList.add(icon3);
    iconList.add(icon4);
    iconList.add(icon5);
    iconList.add(icon6);
}
```

So I created an array list of retire buttons. The condition I set for the timer to stop is if the array list of retire buttons size reaches 12 (which is the total number of buttons in the game), then the timer would stop; however, it just keeps going. I don't what I'm doing wrong. Please help thank you.

Comment: Please learn about the [mcve] construct, where you isolate your problem by condensing the code to the smallest that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem for us. This is useful when asking questions here since it makes it much easier for us to understand your code and your problem, but more to the point, it also makes it much easier for *you* to see the problem and be able to debug it yourself.

Comment: 1. Have you debugged the program. 2. Including have you tested and made sure that game-over detection actually works, and that code that tries to stop the Timer is actually called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a problem I see -- you're creating a **lot** of Timer instances, you're putting them into the swTimer variable, but only trying to stop the last one while all the others continue to run. One possible solution -- before creating a new Timer instance, see if one is currently running, and if so, stop it.

e.g.,

```
private void timerStart() {
    ActionListener timerAL = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateTime();
        }
    };
    // check if swTimer is not null and is currently running
    if (swTimer != null && swTimer.isRunning()) {
        swTimer.stop(); // !! if so STOP it!
    }
    swTimer = new Timer(1000, timerAL);
    swTimer.start();
}
```

But having said that, do you really need to create all these new Timer instances? Wouldn't a single instance work, one started when the first button is pressed and only stopped when the game is over?

Side issues (unrelated to the problem at hand):

- This doesn't belong: `MemoryGame extends JToggleButton`. The game is most definitely **not** a JToggleButton and so you shouldn't have the class extend this class.
- Your game logic is convoluted, hard to test, and may be off a bit. Best to separate the logic from the GUI so you can independently test it with a non-gui battery of tests to see if it is working correctly.